# Can this Aussie drawdown the funds in 'Traditional IRA ' by way of Credit Card

Tags: ira

I am an Australia Citizen by birth. 
I lived / married an American Citizen (by Birth).

My ex Husband set up our IRA's while married.

I hold a Traditional IRA with a Financial firm in USA. 
I am now 61 years young.
Divorced from US Husband.
My traditional IRA was set up in 1987, and was then subject to Tax on withdrawal.
I have retired from full time employment.

I returned to Australia and left my IRA to do its thing, with the investment firm.

I do not hold a great deal of faith with the company the IRA is currently with. It is extremely difficult to get correct information from them and as such Im looking at two-three options:

1) I would like to Draw Down my IRA by way of using an attached Credit Card, for daily living expenses, while still living perm in Au.

2) Can I have the money placed into a TransferWise account for when I travel?  (to access anywhere in the world)

3) If there is no such option ( CC drawdown/TransferWise ) either by way of Legally or no Financial firm offer this, then....

How can I access my money from Australia.

Q) Will the firm Im currently invested with, pay the Federal Taxes?

Q) I have heard that I can Withdraw $12K per year and NOT attract US Tax.Is this correct?

Q) If I previously lived in CA, do I also pay State Tax on my IRA?

Failing the Drawdown by using a Credit Card scenario:
Question "How do I access my money and NOT have it placed into any Bank Accounts in Aust"

My Children hold US Bank Accounts and are American Citizens.
Q) Can I gift it to them?

Thanks for reading.

Comment: "by way of using an attached Credit Card". Given that it's a US account, it would be an attached **debit** card. "Will the firm Im currently invested with, pay the Federal Taxes?"  It's your money; why should they pay taxes on it?

Comment: You might want to ask your financial firm for an IRA distribution form. I highly doubt any institution will accept a credit card account. Paper check or transfer to a bank account are the only options I've seen.